# Hide List-View web part when no item is slected

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, modern-experience, connected-web-parts

Added a list web-part and list-view web part in SharePoint modern page.

But when no item is selected, the list-view web part is displaying grey with connection details which is not looking good.

So, how to hide the web part until a item is selected?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using list properties web part, for now we cannot hide the web part based on such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the only way to edit list items without the List-View web part is just clicking on "Title with edit link" which opens a editable dialogue or in new tab and can make your changes.